# should i be checking for jquery before enqueing it in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

At the start of a typical plugin which uses jquery I have something like the following

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Which as I understand it deregisters and re-enqueues jquery ( from google in this example but that's irrelevant here )

My question is this: is there not some way of checking to see whether the library is already enqueued ( by another plugin or the theme) to save needless deregister/register and enqueue ( or is this not very expensive in reality )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enqueues are not piling up if done multiple times (that is kinda the point of having a queue).

As for registration - frankly it shouldn't be done by most (public) plugins. WordPress comes with jQuery to use and when that copy is re-registered to something else - it affects all plugin and theme code that depends on it.

If it's private code - just do registration once somewhere, no need to duplicate it.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand. Are you talking about getting jquery from Google? I didnt think there was in effect any real difference between the code above and just wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); I thought that was a different argument with it's own pros and cons .... can i just clarify are you saying that even if wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); is called 20 times in the site it makes no notable difference ( becauase it's an enqueue)

Comment: @byronyasgur there is possible difference in jQuery version and WP loads its jQuery in noConflict mode, while Google does not. _even if wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); is called 20 times in the site it makes no notable difference ( becauase it's an enqueue)_ - yes.

Comment: I think I see your point about the google version. In fact just before I read this it was beginning to dawn on me that the WP version updates with WP; wheras the google version needs manual updating ( of the line of code ). That on it's own would convince me to use the built in WP version, but the noConflict issue nails it. Thanks

Comment: _*Click*_ !! ... all (eg 20) the enqueues sum up to just one enqueue - then if that script has been enqueued it is printed with print_scripts .. am I right ?

Comment: @byronyasgur yep. Enqueue is declaration of which scripts need to be loaded, then print sorts out all requests and deals with echoing required scripts in required order.